# Write a query to return "transposed" result in Snowflake

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I have a Snowflake table named EXAMPLE:

**NOTE:** This is an example table with the same structure as my actual table but the data is not at all representative of my actual table. This structure makes complete sense for the kind of data I am storing.

| row_num (not primary key) | item_name (uuid) | category_name (varchar) | value (float) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | item_1 | cat_1 | 1.0 |
| 2. | item_1 | cat_1 | 5.0 |
| 3. | item_1 | cat_2 | 1.1 |
| 4. | item_1 | cat_3 | 1.2 |
| 5. | item_1 | cat_3 | 4.0 |
| 6. | item_1 | cat_4 | 1.3 |
| 7. | item_2 | cat_1 | 1.4 |
| 8. | item_2 | cat_1 | 6.0 |
| 9. | item_2 | cat_2 | 1.5 |
| 10. | item_2 | cat_5 | 1.6 |
| 11. | item_2 | cat_6 | 1.7 |
| 12. | item_2 | cat_7 | 1.8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| n-3. | item_n | cat_1 | 1.9 |
| n-2. | item_n | cat_4 | 2.0 |
| n-1. | item_n | cat_7 | 2.1 |
| n. | item_n | cat_9 | 2.2 |

I need to write a query to fetch data transposed in following way:

| category_name | i_1 | i_2 | ... | i_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat_1 | 1.0 | 1.4 | ... | 1.9 |
| cat_1 | 5.0 | 6.0 | ... | NULL |
| cat_2 | 1.1 | 1.5 | ... | NULL |
| cat_3 | 1.2 | NULL | ... | NULL |
| cat_3 | 4.0 | NULL | ... | NULL |
| cat_4 | 1.3 | NULL | ... | 2.0 |
| cat_5 | NULL | 1.6 | ... | NULL |
| cat_6 | NULL | 1.7 | ... | NULL |
| cat_7 | NULL | 1.8 | ... | 2.1 |
| cat_9 | NULL | NULL | ... | 2.2 |

I have tried following:

1. [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT CATEGORY_NAME, "'ITEM_1'" AS I_1, "'ITEM_2'" AS I_2, "'ITEM_N'" AS I_N FROM EXAMPLE
PIVOT(SUM(VALUE) FOR ITEM_NAME IN ('ITEM_1', 'ITEM_2', 'ITEM_N')) AS P ORDER BY CATEGORY_NAME)
WHERE
I_1 IS NOT NULL OR I_2 IS NOT NULL OR I_N IS NOT NULL
```

This returns desired result as long as there is no repetition of a category for a given item. This is because an aggregate function must be used with PIVOT. As soon as a category repeats for any item, it will aggregate its value which is not what I want as a result.

2. CTEs (Common Table Expressions):

```
WITH
CTE1 (CTE1_CATEGORY_NAME, CTE1_ITEM1) AS (SELECT CATEGORY_NAME, ITEM_NAME FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ITEM_NAME = 'ITEM_1'),
CTE2 (CTE2_CATEGORY_NAME, CTE2_ITEM2) AS (SELECT CATEGORY_NAME, ITEM_NAME FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ITEM_NAME = 'ITEM_2')
SELECT CTE1_CATEGORY_NAME, CTE1_ITEM1, CTE2_ITEM2 FROM CTE1 FULL OUTER JOIN CTE2
```

This is incorrect because I am selecting CATEGORY_NAME only from CTE1 where as I need a range of `category_name` values from all CTEs in a single column. I don't know how do I produce such range of values from all CTEs. Also, the above query is only for 2 items and I can't figure out how do I extend it for n items.

**EDIT:**

I was able to get this work for 2 items thru:

```
WITH
CTE1 (CTE1_CATEGORY_NAME, CTE1_ITEM1) AS (SELECT CATEGORY_NAME, ITEM_NAME FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ITEM_NAME = 'ITEM_1'),
CTE2 (CTE2_CATEGORY_NAME, CTE2_ITEM2) AS (SELECT CATEGORY_NAME, ITEM_NAME FROM EXAMPLE WHERE ITEM_NAME = 'ITEM_2'),
CTE3 (CTE3_CATEGORY_NAME) AS (SELECT CTE1_CATEGORY_NAME FROM CTE1 UNION ALL SELECT CTE2_CATEGORY_NAME FROM CTE2),
CTE4 (CTE4_CATEGORY_NAME1, CTE4_ITEM1, CTE4_CATEGORY_NAME2, CTE4_ITEM2) AS (SELECT CTE1_CATEGORY_NAME, CTE1_ITEM1, CTE2_CATEGORY_NAME, CTE2_ITEM2 FROM CTE1 FULL OUTER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1_ITEM1 = CTE2_ITEM2)
SELECT CTE3_CATEGORY_NAME, CTE4_ITEM1, CTE4_ITEM2 FROM CTE3
INNER JOIN CTE4
ON CTE3_CATEGORY_NAME = CTE4_CATEGORY_NAME1 OR CTE3_CATEGORY_NAME = CTE4_CATEGORY_NAME2
```

Could someone please help with optimizing the query and extending it for n items? The original requirement is that I will receive a list of item names in a function from where I have to generate an SQL statement and submit to Snowflake for execution. The final result must be saved in a parquet file in Snowflake stage.

Comment: Hi - when a category repeats for any item, what value do you want to show? Can you just use a different aggregate function e.g. MAX or ANY_VALUE?

Comment: Hi @NickW, no I can't use any aggregate function because I need both the values for that category for that item in the result.

Comment: what does it mean to "get both results" two rows?, or two column with the same name?

Comment: No, two columns can't have the same name. The column names in the result should represent the items. Is that what you wanted to know? Could you please explain your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following code may achieve what you want. If you have an unknown number of item values (or category values) then you'd have to build the code dynamically in a SP.

```
WITH ALL_DATA AS (
 SELECT *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY_NAME, ITEM_NAME ORDER BY CATEGORY_NAME, ITEM_NAME) GROUP_NUM
FROM EXAMPLE
)
,PIV_DATA AS (
SELECT CATEGORY_NAME, GROUP_NUM, "'item_1'" AS ITEM_1, "'item_2'" as ITEM_2
  FROM ALL_DATA A
    PIVOT(MAX(VALUE) FOR item_name IN ('item_1', 'item_2'))
      AS p
)
SELECT
CATEGORY_NAME, MIN(ITEM_1), MIN(ITEM_2)
FROM PIV_DATA
GROUP BY CATEGORY_NAME, GROUP_NUM
ORDER BY CATEGORY_NAME, GROUP_NUM
;
```

Comment: It is still using an aggregate function in the `PIVOT` and also, I could not understand the reason of using `MIN(ITEM_1)` and `MIN(ITEM_2)`. Could you please help?

Comment: The GROUP BY is used to consolidate multiple rows into  one;  as there is only one value being aggregated (the other values in the column in the same group are null) it has the same affect as just selecting the value. Which aggregate function you use doesn’t really matter, I could have equally used MAX instead of MIN

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the explanation and help! I added one more check on PIV_DATA where rows having NULL for all item columns will be eliminated.